# getUserMedia API suport for Opera Local screen share

Tags: opera, webrtc, getusermedia, browser-extension, opera-extension

I am creating an Opera extension that will open a webpage which will allow user to stream a local window on to the browser html file. Since Opera extension structure is similar to the chrome, I tested the structure on Opera.

For manifest having permissons :

```
 "permissions": ["desktopCapture","activeTab"],
```

Error :

```
There were warnings when trying to install this extension:
Permission 'desktopCapture' is unknown or URL pattern is malformed.
```

And for using the method :

```
chrome.desktopCapture.chooseDesktopMedia(["screen", "window"], onAccessApproved);
```

Console error :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'chooseDesktopMedia' of undefined
```

Is there some documentation available for Opera regarding getUserMedia API usage that can help in the matter
Already gone through :
* https://dev.opera.com/articles/getusermedia-access-camera-privacy-ui/
* https://dev.opera.com/tags/getusermedia/
* WebRTC official page

Comment: [Take a look here](http://iswebrtcreadyyet.com/) to see what aspects of WebRTC are supported by whom.

Comment: thanks Benjamin. Yes saw that while looking out for solutions..

Answer (score 1):

The desktopCapture is not supported in Opera yet so you can't use it. There is no other way to share other application window I could see to work now.

Comment: Thanks Lukasz.. had been exploing solutions for quite a while now.. guess we have to wait until opera supports further chrome APIs